# Infinite power tower paradox with e and pi.

Tags: calculus, number-theory, trigonometry, power-towers

I was experimenting with Euler's Identity.  If $e^{((\pi*i)/2)}$ is $i$, couldn't you recursively plug in $i$ into the expression.  For example: 
$$e^{((\pi/2)*e^{((\pi/2)*e^{((\pi/2)*e^{((\pi/2)*e^{((\pi/2)*e^{((\pi/2)*e^{((\pi/2)i)))))))}}}}}}}.
$$

That should be equal to $i$.  So you could plug that whole thing in for the $i$ in the equation, giving a new equation equaling $i$, so that new equation can be plugged into itself.  If you do this an infinite number of times, you wind up with an infinitely large power tower which uses only positive numbers, and equals $i$.  The farther you go to this expression, the closer it should get to $i$.  Logically it can never equal $i$ when you apply the recursion a finite number of times, but it can go to $0$, which is the closest it can get.  However, when you plug this in, it quickly zooms off towards infinity, not $0$.  Could you help me resolve this?

Comment: I think you need to do some major editing in your exponential expression. Can you type it using LaTeX? Also try to clarify some of the language. It's not clear exactly what you mean to say...

Comment: +1. I quite like this question - it's a good example of the difficulties that arise when we try to evaluate infinite expressions. (Although at the end of the day, the complex analysis aspect is a red herring.)

Comment: Although the power tower is clearly divergent, it can be analytically continued in a similar method to (11) and (12) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html) with $z=e^{\pi/2}$ to give $h \pi/2=\ln(h)$, which analytically solves as $h=\pm i$, which you would recursively expect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your "infinite tower" indeed does *not* equal $i$, but rather shoots off to infinity. The error is your sentence

> If you do this an infinite number of times, you wind up with an infinitely large power tower which uses only positive numbers, **and equals $i$**

specifically, the part in bold.

---

Basically, your problem is that the evaluation of an infinite expression has to be done very carefully.

Here's a much simpler version of your paradox:

- Clearly $1\times 0=0$.
- So we can plug in "$1\times 0$" in place of "$0$", above, to get $1\times 1\times 0=0$.
- We can iterated this indefinitely, and the "limit expression" is $1\times 1\times 1\times 1 \times\dots $
- . . . but this clearly *isn't* equal to $0$!

What's going on, basically, is that:

- The sequence of *expressions* $1\times 0, 1\times 1\times 0, 1\times 1\times 1\times 0, \dots$ **does** approach (in an appropriate sense) the infinite expression $1\times 1\times 1\times \dots$.
- However, the *evaluation* operation - think of this roughly as a function $ev$ from $\{$expressions$\}$ to $\{$numbers$\}$ - is *not continuous* in the appropriate sense: that is, $$\mbox{$\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} L_i=L\quad$ does not imply $\quad \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} (ev(L_i))=ev(L)$.}$$
- This, in turn, is just a recasting of the standard example from calculus: let $f_i(x)=1$ if $x>i$, and $0$ otherwise; then $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f_i(x)=1$, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}f_i(x)=0$. Do you see why?

(Note that I'm sweeping a whole ton under the rug in terms of what "$ev$" is exactly - my point is just that, merely because we have some way of evaluating some infinite expressions, doesn't mean that that evaluation method is "nice" in any intuitive sense.)

---

A similar issue is at play in the popular joke argument that $\pi=4$ (see https://qntm.org/trollpi); what's going on is that, depending on how we *topologize* the set of all "reasonable" curves in the plane,

- EITHER the "length" function is not continuous,
- OR the sequence of jagged approximations doesn't actually approach the circle.

Depending on what you're trying to do, one or the other option may be better; but you can't avoid both simultaneously!

Comment: "does approach (in an appropriate sense)" I don't see how that sequences approaches 1 x 1 x ... Which appropriate sense?  . One can say though that 1 x 1 x ... is defined ambiguously, and needs to be specified rigorously, such as with a sequence.

Comment: @Theta33 I'm not talking about the *value of* the sequence, I'm talking about the *literal sequence of symbols itself*. If I think just in terms of strings, the sequence of strings $$a_0b,\quad a_0a_1b,\quad a_0a_1a_2b,\quad ...$$ approaches the string $$a_0a_1a_2...$$ (this can be made precise by putting an appropriate topology on the space of finite-or-infinite strings over the relevant alphabet). The point is that evaluation is then a (partial) function from strings to numbers, and it is **not continuous** in the relevant sense.

Comment: (BTW this is a bit finicky, so you may have additional questions; I recommend asking them as a separate MSE post rather than continuing this comment thread.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $w=\exp(\pi/2)$ then your problem reads as follows:

- Let  $x_0=i$ , then $x_1=w^{x_0} = i $, $x_2 = w^{x_1}= i$ , ... and
  this can be repeated arbitrarily often.

I think, it is more appropriately (and then -in my view completely legitimate-) denoted as a  formula
$$ i=\large      \, _{_{_ {_ {...}}}}     \, _{_{_w}} \, _{_w} \small \, _w i  \tag 1  $$
This reflects, that we deal actually with an *"exponential-tower"* (because we iterate to stack iteratively *bases* to an exponential expression and not *powers* ). Unfortunately it cannot be nicely rendered in latex.

However, $i$ is a *repelling* fixpoint for the base $w$ *("repelling": that means, a slight  deviation in the exponent leads to increase of that initial deviance when iterated)* so
the version, in which you denote the problem, $i=w^{w^{w^\cdots}}$ *without* actually the $i$ in the top position, ***does not converge*** , and the reason for this was already found by Goldbach and Euler when they discovered, that the exponential tower of increasing height converges only for real bases $b$ when $1/e^e < b <e^{1/e} \approx 1.44 $ and $ e^{1/e} \approx 1.44 \lt w \approx 4.81$
*(Additional remark: to relate this to complex bases $b$ it might be interesting for you to look for D. Shell und W. Thron and the "Shell-Thron-region" for complex bases, see for instance wikipedia in the article on tetration)*